# android - read a javascript variable from webview

Tags: android, webview

I want to read value of a javascript variable within a webview in a simple activity.

is it possible to get it from?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991515/android-extract-javascript-variable-from-webview-using-javascript-interface ?

Comment: Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661033/android-webview-call-activity-methods-form-javascript-interface?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i convert a javascript variable to a java string variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790363/how-can-i-convert-a-javascript-variable-to-a-java-string-variable)